# Unresolved Reference in Android Studios

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, textview

I'm new to android studio. I have installed android studio 4.2.0 and run the application on Windows 10 with i5, 8GB ram and NVIDIA MX230 Graphics. I'm simply trying to change text of a TextView named "firstText" using the .kt file as follows:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       firstText.text = "Welcome humans"
    }
}
```

The firstText throws an error as "unresolved reference" and for the .text it throws "variable expected". What should I do to get this working?

Comment: Have you obtained the reference of your `TextView` from xml into this `firstText` variable ?

Comment: The stuff about "android studio 4.2.0" and "Windows 10 with i5, 8GB ram and NVIDIA MX230 Graphics" is completely irrelevant.  Q: Did you ever declare variable "firstText"?

Comment: What you are trying to do is available in `kotlin synthetic ` which is Deprecated in earlier version AFAIK

Comment: @AnaniyaJemberu That just might be it. Thanks a lot. I will look into other ways to do the same with the new kotlin version.

Comment: @NisanthReddy I'll try that. I wanted to know why it was not working like they did in the tutorial. Found the reason. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

open app/src/build.gradle .In the file replace

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
}
```

with

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

save everthing restart everthing. it will work.